# How to check if string including within parentheses is in list?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop, search

I am trying to use my code to find titles which include strings "include_these_titles" and filters out "disqualifying terms"

```
titles = [
'Document And Entity Information (USD $)',
'Consolidated Statements of Operations (USD $)',
'Consolidated Statements of Operations (Parenthetical) (USD $)',
'General and Summary of Significant Accounting Policies'
]

include_these_titles = [
"consolidated statement of operations",
"consolidated statements of operations",
]

disqualifying_terms = ["paren","paran", "(parenthetical)", "paran", "(Parenthetical)"]

for sheet_title in titles:
    if any(x in sheet_title for x in include_these_titles):
        if any(x in sheet_title for x in disqualifying_terms):
            print(sheet_title)
```

Should Return only :

```
consolidated statements of operations (usd $)
```

but currently returns

```
consolidated statements of operations (usd $)
consolidated statements of operations (parenthetical) (usd $)
```

Comment: what should it return?

Comment: just consolidated statements of operations (usd $) I would like to filter out anything with parenthetical in it

Comment: can you give an example of expected output?

Comment: consolidated statements of operations (usd $)

Comment: Please edit the expected output into the question. When I try to run your code, I get sheet_title is not defined.

Comment: Ok but sheet title is a list of titles from an excel sheet. and this sits in a bigger loop but I will edit now

Comment: I added full code and a list of some of the titles from the xlsx sheet if you want the actual sheet I can give you a link to sec to download?

Comment: Easy there. We don't want your entire database. Just define a working value for sheet_title that illustrates the problem.

Comment: It should loop through the list of titles  and each title will be the sheet_title and check if its in the list of unwanted / income statement and reutn Consolidated Statements of Operations (USD $) as I want to rename that sheet

Comment: sheet_title = 'Consolidated Statements of Operations (USD $)'

Comment: It needs to be dynamic as I am doing this for like 3 companies in its sector each use a different name for the I/S

Comment: thats why I am trying to capture the names for the statement in the income_statement list but I need to filter out the paran~ as that also gets caught

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220148/discussion-between-kenny-ostrom-and-jpwilson).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for substring matches from a whitelist of lowercase terms, but you are checking for them in a capitalized string.

This may be the test you're looking for:

```
any(x in sheet_title.lower() for x in include_these_titles)
```

Additionally, if you're wanting to disqualify terms, perhaps you want "not any" on that step. You'll need exact matches, unless you want to use lower() there, as well.

```
for sheet_title in titles:
    if any(x in sheet_title.lower() for x in include_these_titles):
        if not any(x in sheet_title for x in disqualifying_terms):
            print(sheet_title)
```

Comment: I did adjust for lower originally. the If not any solved it I think! I did not know you could do that so thanks so much!